# Cannot access Tor - Please help

Tags: configuration

Up until a few days ago, I could access Tor every time I clicked the "Start Tor Browser". Since then, no luck. 
Here is where I am at.

1. I use Norton Internet Security. Deleted and setup Tor as trusted
   connection several times.
2. Each time I try to connect to Tor, I see `tor.exe` and `firefox.exe`
   as running processes but Tor does not start.
3. I do not even get to see the Tor Configuration Box.
4. I installed BlackBeltPrivacy - Vidalia and when I click "Connect to 
   Tor" and I get to see some success in the message "Tor is running"
5. When I go to click "Start Tor Browser" nothing happens
6. After a few minutes, I then get a Crash Report from Mozilla Firefox.

I really do not know what to do and would appreciate any help.

I have saved some log files if that will help.

```
May 08 22:52:52.597 [Notice] Tor v0.2.7.6 running on Windows 7 with
  Libevent 2.1.5-beta, OpenSSL 1.0.2g and Zlib 1.2.8.
May 08 22:52:52.704 [Notice] Read configuration file 
  "C:\Users\Ravi Nimsons\AppData\Local\BlackBeltPrivacy\Config\BlackBeltPrivacy.torrc"
May 08 22:52:52.704 [Warning] Path for DataDirectory 
  (C:/Users/Ravi Nimsons/AppData/Local/BlackBeltPrivacy/RuntimeData) 
  is relative and will resolve to 
  C:\Users\Ravi Nimsons\AppData\Local\BlackBeltPrivacy\RuntimeData. 
  Is this what you wanted?
```

Comment: It seems there is no problem with Tor. The problem seems to be with firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Tor log is fine, it's working and it's OK. A Tor Browser issue is in order : try to remove addons from it or use a separate Firefox with FoxyProxy.

UPDATE: the edit suggested is a question - it's OK to ask further but a proper place for corresponding questions is a comment. You don't need to remove a firefox - a multiple separated instances of FF are coexisting just fine, I'm using them myself(two of them). Just install to a separate folder