# Tor update from 5.5.5 to 6.0

Tags: update

Bonjour,

Up til now Tor 5.5.5. worked very well.
After update to tor 6.0 the browser does not start.Nothing happens.
Wow can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: Apologize if this is not the correct way to respond - I am a new poster and am unable to respond by commenting so have added my comments via the Answer box. I too am a new user and have the same issue after upgrading to the latest version of Tor on my Window 7 system. There was a similar question asked previously that mirrors my situation. https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/10385/cannot-access-tor-please-help ;
Cannot access Tor - Please help One of the answer stated to run FireFox in a separate folder? Thanks for the assist

Comment: Do you have Trusteer Rapport installed?